How to achieve this: after function execution, everything gets restored to the state before calling it. Can fork be used to implement it?
I found myself occasionally need to do "probe" version of a function.
As a simple example, when developing evaluator, I might want to do a tentative evaluation to see whether current dependency info is enough or not. In this case, I'll call the eval function as if it is a probe, i.e., I only care its return value of bool that indicates succ/fail. Most importantly, as this is only a tentative attempt, I would like to keep everything intact throughout the execution, in other words, no data such as dependency/counter/memoi/etc is different before and after the probing.
Now, if the probe function is simple enough, certainly I can make a new function mimicking the old one except for that every write operation is instead made on a deepcopy, etc.
However, if the function has some thousand lines of code with logic so intertwined. Writing a new one is no longer practical. I can only rely on regression system to help identify as many issues as possible and bear the potential risk.
I hence wonder

Is there any well defined way to achieve that?
Can fork be used to implement it on Linux? that is, parent proc simply do nothing but wait for child proc, child does the probe function and pass target value to parent by pipe. If my memory is not rusted so badly, fork uses copy-on-write scheme, it hence appeals to resemble the flow discussed above, and I'll expect the overhead to be relatively low. Any hazard doing it?

EDIT:
As an attempt to make this question more specific, I would like to apply some restrictions to the probe function:

It is guaranteed that such function does not talk to external process in any way, i.e., no network socket, no RPC, etc. To even further simplify, let's for now also assume there exists no local IPC.
This function contains nothing indeterministic, i.e., no need to worry about touching random_device, curandstate, etc.
It is guaranteed that the function will reach the return point provided that no exception is thrown. If any exception is thrown during the execution, simply catch all at top of the function call, print a message and forfeit the probing.
Any other to make this question clearer? kindly teach.

UPDATE:
I did some experiments on fork scheme, it turns out that, for several 100 to 250 lines functions within which other functions are nested with a relatively complex logic, this solution get a clean regression result. The probe seems to indeed leave the context intact.
Also, by playing with GDB I verified fork even copies register, it seems to me a workaround at least for now.
Given the restrictions discussed in the EDIT, is there any potential issue I shall expect and pay attention to? I managed to search for similar usage of fork but no luck.
Any comment and answer for other solution is still most welcome.

Hi folks, why vote close, mind teaching?

It is an interesting question that I do not feel qualified to answer, but I am curious why you cannot implement checks for the resources you may be missing at the top of a function, and return a status before attempting any execution? It would be helpful to have an example of such a case where you would prefer to attempt this 'probe' function through execution vs testing. I am imagining a function which requires a file for instance, and I can see no reason to try and fail operations on the file, vs checking if the file exists right at function start. Maybe you could clarify that

Hi @DouglasB, many thanks for your comment. For your check at top scheme, it is, IMHO, equivalently the same as doing a new function scheme, as you'll need to find out all the places that may contribute to the result, also, not all data can be get off shelf, some data needs to be processed other functions to produce needed temporary data, etc. Those functions themselves may utilize memoi, counter, log, etc, to optimize or record cared info, for the test scheme you give, it must also leave them intact.

Without any restrictions it is impossible to say what a function does or how to prevent or undo its operations, especially if it can modify something external.  A function could shut down your operating system or attempt to delete the internet, good luck to try to restore that. This reminds me a bit of the Halting Problem.

Hi @Thibe, thanks for bringing up the possible definition, it greatly helps my literature search and so on. I totally agreed your point on possible external interaction, but now let's just assume the program does not have any network IPC to simplify.

Please write the limitations in your question. I assume the votes for closure came because the question as right now is too broad and not solvable for every type of function.

This question could use some clearer definitions of what lies within the program's control and what does not. If your function touches something external to the program, restoring it to the previous state would need some RAII-like constructs - and it may not even be possible. Like @Thibe I'm thinking of irreversible states, such as the one you're in after your proble happens to indirectly call [[noreturn]] void selfDestruct() noexcept;. Could you provide a [mre] to showcase the setup? longjmp may be an actual answer...

Hi Thibe and TedLyngmo, I edited the question, any further suggestions and answers are greatly appreciated.

@PkDrew Re: "any further suggestions" - Yes, my original suggestion still stands. If you provide a [mre] we can actually see what we're dealing with.

@TedLyngmo, As I stated at description, the reason why I hack so hard is I want a scheme that applies to arbitrarily complex function as long as it doesn’t violate the regulation. I am afraid such function is not minimum reproducible. That said, I’ll see whether I can make a code demonstrate why state restore is asked.

You can try to write your 'function' as an object method, with proper encapsulation.
Then either:

have a const 'probe' method which does the evaluation and returns a bool (or throws) - without modifying the instance
or make the object clonable/copyable. To probe, copy it, call the method, and drop the copy.

Using fork() to do that is probably a very bad idea, unless you really know what you do and have absolutely no other solution.
If you really have socket connections, and the probe touches them, you can't guarantee no side-effect (unless all your socket accesses are idempotent), so it is likely unfeasible.
Sorry I can't be really more precise as your question is quite vague...

Could you elaborate why fork is bad for this?

Because, as you tagged c++, you should be concerned by efficiency. Using fork will be at least 2 orders of magnitude slower than doing it properly in-process, and won't scale.
It will also be more complex to implement properly, debug and optimize. And won't be portable to Windows - if you care. (Yes I know WSL, just wait a few more years for windows to boot a linux kernel and run the 'legacy' windows apps in an hypervisor !).
If you searched and found nobody doing something similar, either you are the genius of the century, or most people are just a bit more clever... Let you chose.

Many thanks for the explanation. For porting to Windows, it is relatively a minor issue as cross platform migration inevitably comes with feature disabling and so on. For performance, however, indeed much care needs to be taken, to my knowledge, modern Linux achieves a relatively low overhead even compared to thread, is the two orders of magnitude an up-to-date figure? any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry I won't google that for you... It's like asking why pizza deliveries don't use humvees instead of light vehicles !
